# Should I publish results from my conference presentation as a conference paper or as a journal article?

Tags: publications, conference

I presented some results during a colloquium a few months ago and now I can send an article to be reviewed by peers and published into a book. My concern is that this is not as interesting as being published in a real journal (especially a Q1).

The problem is, if a don't publish it in the book edited by the colloquium organization, I can't add that presentation to ResearchGate, ORCID, etc. since those platforms ask to upload a paper. So I would end up with only a paper on my resumé and no evidence of the nice presentation I did.

I suppose that it's weird to publish a conference paper AND an article with the same data, so my questions are: is there a way to add a presentation to those platforms without publishing a conference paper? What would you do?

Comment: You can add presentations on researchgate, when you click on "add research", there is the option to select "presentation".

Comment: "I suppose that it's weird to publish a conference paper AND an article with the same data" Depends on your field. Some fields do that all the time, IIRC.